# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 512 Kb

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, memory, maps

I'm trying to run code in Rstudio to graph a map. However, I get an error message: User
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 512 Kb. As I understand it, it's an error due to my system's memory. The script has few lines of code, and weighs no more than 2kb. And the object I want to graph has more than 559,000 observations. My computer has 12 GB of memory, and when I run the script it uses almost all of the memory. What alternatives are there for my problem? Thanks!

Comment: My guess is freeing up memory as you go by explicitly calling `rm(some_larg_object)` here and there in your script but there isn't anything to debug in this question so I cannot be sure.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean there is nothing to debug in the question? Tell me and I'll give you more details. Thanks!

Comment: We cannot reproduce the issue on our computers, so there is only generic advice that doesn't take into account the details of the problem.

Comment: The alternative might be generalizing your observations. So, instead of plotting 559,000 of points on the relative small map, you may aggregate them (by geographical coordinates for example, or by observation type, or by other attribute) and plot the results.